# How do you write "outprioritize"?

Tags: grammaticality, vocabulary

I often hear "outprioritize" spoken, like:

> Request **X** outprioritizes request **Y**

But it's not a word, so how should it be written? Out prioritize? Out-prioritize? Neither?

Comment: What makes you say "it's not a word?" Though it doesn't yet appear in the standard dictionaries I have looked in, my understanding is that it is a word which means 'to override in importance'. Google, for instance, finds many occurrences of the term.

Comment: @ErikKowal: It does? I've Googled all the variations I can think of and found basically no results :S That's why I'm asking here

Comment: At my time/space coordinates, my [search](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS577US577&espv=2&q=%22outprioritize%22&oq=%22outprioritize%22&gs_l=serp.3..30i10.23948.25656.0.26656.2.2.0.0.0.0.112.192.1j1.2.0.msedr...0...1c.1.60.serp..0.2.191.ZbtpmhYXuSI) for "outprioritize" resulted in 7250 hits just now.

Comment: @ErikKowal: Interestingly, the top result is already this question :/

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's not a word -- it's meaning is self-evident to me, and I ascribe to the philosophy that if the listener knows the meaning of the term without prior agreement then it's a word -- but it doesn't seem to be in widespread usage.

However, it sounds somewhat awkward to my ears.  I might prefer "outrank" or "supersede" unless "priority" were a term specific to the context, but then we're probably talking about jargon or some other *ad hoc* terminology rather than English.  If I had to spell it, I would probably keep it two words or hyphenate it as "out-prioritize" simply because it's not used widely enough to be readily identifiable.

Answer (score -2):

How... and why? How about "Request X is more important than request Y"?

If you insist on unnecessarily making new words, use the hyphen.  Pushing the words together suggests you don't even know you are doing it; the space is just wrong.